# cordova sqlite - problem with selecting from database

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to get my cordova app to work. I added cordova-sqlite-storage plugin and there's a problem with getting data from the database. I tried several things and the result of select is "undefined" or the transaction doesn't work at all.

Thank you in advance

opening database seems to be working (based on cordova documentation and sample):

````
var DB;
var onDeviceReady = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (document.URL.match(/^https?:/i)) {
        console.log("Running in a browser...");
        resolve();
    } else {
        console.log("Running in an app...");
        runiOS = true;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", resolve, false);
    }
});
onDeviceReady.then(function () {
    if (runiOS) {
        DB = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'}, function (db) {}, function (error) {
            console.log('Open database ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
        console.log('DB: SQLite');
    } else {
        DB = window.openDatabase('my', "0.1", "My list", 200000);
        console.log('DB: WebSQL');
    }
   
    DB.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT count(*) AS countID FROM Messages', [], function (tx, rs) {
            console.log(rs.rows.item(0).countID);
            countID = rs.rows.item(0).countID;
            console.log(countID);
        }, function (tx, error) {
        });
    });
}); ```


adding seems to be working too:

    function addToDB() {
  
  DB.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages (id int AUTO_INCREMENT, mess MEDIUMTEXT)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Messages (mess) VALUES (?)', ["sample value"]);
      console.log('added');
    
  });
}

but there's a problem with select and I don't know why:

function getFromDB() {
    DB.transaction(function (tx) {
        
        tx.executeSql(('SELECT mess FROM Messages WHERE id="2"', function (tx, results) {
        console.log(results.rows.item(0).mess);
    }));
    });
};
````

Comment: Why quote the id? It's an int, so doesn't need to be quoted. Besides, double quotes are usually (I'm not very familiar with sqlite) reserved for object identifiers, literal strings are quoted with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I simply don't see how you detect "device ready". But I'm pretty sure you don't actually wait for Cordova's device ready, which means that your code runs too early before the plugins have init.
Wait for Cordova's Device Ready event. Also it does not return a Promise.